# How can I print a string received as XDR?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming, xdr

I have a client and a server which communicate eache other with a socket using the XDR notation. Unix environment. The server send a string to client correctly (I checked the number of bytes sended, it is correct), the client receive the string but it is not correct, because the printf print NULL.

Code server: b is a (char **)

```
xdrmem_create (&xdrs_w, buffer, MAXBUFL, XDR_ENCODE);
xdr_string(&xdrs_w, &b, 32);
strcpy(b, "ciaociao");
printf("I am sending: %s\n", b);
Writen (socketID2, b, strlen(b));
xdr_destroy(&xdrs_w);
```

Instead, this is the client code:

```
xdrmem_create(&xdrs_r, buffer, MAXBUFL, XDR_DECODE);
Read (socketID, buffer, 8);    
xdr_string(&xdrs_r, &bf, 32);
buffer[8]='\0';
printf("Result: %s\n",bf);  /NULL?!?!
xdr_destroy(&xdrs_r);
```

Any idea? Thank you in advice

Comment: How is `bf` declared ?

Comment: Why don't you use an `xdr` directly attached to the network stream? You also can't read 8 bytes and try to decode it as an 8-byte length string (xdr encoding uses length-string encoding).